# Expected an intended block (Python TK library)

Tags: python, tkinter, translation

I am trying to make a simple translator.
The important part of the code:

```
tkVar = tk.StringVar(root)
choices = { "de":'German', "ru":'Russian', "en":'English', "hr":'Croatian', "cz":'Czech', "sv":'Swedish', "pl":'Polish' }
tkVar.set('de')
popUpMenu = tk.OptionMenu(mainframe, tkVar, *choices)
tk.Label(mainframe, text="Choose a language").grid(row=1,column=1)
popUpMenu.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

My functions (russian & german translation only for now):

```
def rustrans():
    word = entry.get()
    translator = Translator(service_urls=["translate.google.com"])
    translation1 = translator.translate(word, dest="ru")
    label1 = tk.Label(root,text=f"Translated in Russian : {translation1.text}", bg="yellow")
    label1.grid(row=2,column=0)

def detrans():
    word = entry.get()
    translator = Translator(service_urls=["translate.google.com"])
    translation2=translator.translate(word, dest="de")
    label2 = tk.Label(root, text=f"Translated in German : {translation2.text}", bg = "yellow")
    label2.grid(row=2,column=0)
```

My attempt at trying to translate from English to said language by using an if statement:

```
if choices["de"]:
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Translate", command=detrans)
    button.grid(row=1,column=2)

if choices["ru"]:
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Translate", command=rustrans)
button1.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

Sublime text says the error is on line 46 aka

```
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Translate", command=rustrans)
```

I am here cause I wanna find out what should I do in case "expected an intended block" occurs.

EDIT: running WITHOUT the WHOLE if choices["ru"] part of the code (by commenting it) the program runs just fine.

Comment: Well, just like the body of the if-statement before it, this if-statement needs its body indented to the right by four spaces.

Comment: _indented_, not intended.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to put the indentation at the start of both the lines after the if choices['ru']:

```
if choices["de"]:
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Translate", command=detrans)
    button.grid(row=1,column=2)

if choices["ru"]:
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Translate", command=rustrans)
    button1.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

Then it should work for you

Answer (score 2):

The issue in your code is here:

```
if choices["ru"]:
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Translate", command=rustrans)
button1.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

You should rewrite that to look like:

```
if choices["ru"]: # indent the code after the colon
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Translate", command=rustrans)
    button1.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

Comment: I now understand what is indentation. You, user10987432 & @Dan fixed my problem :) Have a good day sir!

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help.

Comment: @wANN `Python` is different from other languages in the aspect of indentation. You should do it properly or your `code` won't work.